# Powershell: call Word Sub with parameter doesn't work

Tags: vba, powershell

I have 2 vba subs that I want to call from Powershell ISE; I can call wordsub successfully, but calling wordsub1parameter doesn't trigger msgbox and there's no error in log:

```
Sub wordsub()

MsgBox ("hello from sub")

End Sub

Sub wordsub1parameter(greetings)

MsgBox (greetings)

End Sub
```

Powershell script:

```
$file = "C:\test\test.docx"

$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $True

$Document=$Word.documents.open($file)

$Word.run("wordsub")
$Word.run("wordsub1parameter", "hello")
```

Is it impossible ?

Comment: Does it work when you call `Application.Run()` in VBA?

Comment: @Tomalak thanks $Word.Application.Run("wordsub1parameter", "hello")  works :) you can put the solution I'll mark it as right answer.

Comment: This isn't even what I meant, I meant "try out the call in VBA first before you port it to Powershell", but hey, if it works... I can't really explain why it works, though. Both `$Word` and `$Word.Application` refer to the exact same object - just like `Application` and `Application.Application` do in VBA. It makes no sense that one of the calls fails.

Comment: @Tomalak well seems it does make a difference in practice if not in theory at least when calling from Powershell :)